# How to write this delta-epsilon proof?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to do this proof? I can't seem to get it into a simple form.

**Prove that** $\lim\limits_{x \to 2}\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first require that $|x-2|\le1$ so that $1\le x\le3$.

This implies that $\frac{1}{|x|}\le1$.

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac1x-\frac12\right|&=\frac12 \frac{|x-2|}{|x|}\\\\
&\le \frac12 |x-2|\\\\
&<\epsilon
 \end{align}$$

whenever $|x-2|<\delta =\min\left(1,2\epsilon\right)$

Comment: @user236182 Thank you for that catch!  +1 Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

Now let $\displaystyle \delta =$min$\{1,2\epsilon\}$

Then $|x−2|≤1 \Rightarrow 1≤x≤3 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{|x|}\le 1$.

Observe that $\displaystyle \left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{x-2}{2x}\right|=\frac{|x-2|}{2|x|}\le \frac{\delta}{2}\le \epsilon$

Comment: Just like mine. ;-)

Comment: You were quick at typing I guess !